# What Partition of HDD should Ubuntu be installed?

Tags: boot, boot-partition

1. Does installation of Ubuntu from WUBI require another partition for loading? If it loads on C: then is it and OS Environment only? Kindly explain.
2. Should it be a Primary Partition only? As I understand that only form Primary partition the OS can be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

1. Installing Ubuntu using WUBI (i.e. from within Windows) doesn't require any extra partitions to be created. It simply creates a file on your Windows partition, and adds an entry to the Windows boot loader to boot an OS (Ubuntu) from this image file.

   It also adds an entry to your "Add/Remove Programs" section of Windows so that you can easily remove this Ubuntu image file from your C: (i.e. your Windows partition). The only real downside to this AFAIK is a very slight decrease in speed due to being restrained by the Windows filesystem (NTFS or FAT) speed-wise, but this is only a slight decrease and it's not really noticeable to most users.
2. See (1), WUBI installs don't need any partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

WUBI does not need a partition. It uses a loop device which is a virtual disk therefore it must be installed on a Windows filesystem (C: Drive is OK).